# Responsive Design - Div Columns Within Section Not Styling With Section

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns, background-color

I have a 3 Column Layout, classed "content", within my section. Then, I have three divs within the "content" class, classed "col-4" to determine their width (I'm using the 12 column responsive grid system: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp). In my CSS, section and .content are both styled with "background-color: orange;" but the columns are not turning orange.

[image]

I tried styling each column with "background-color: orange;" but I still get a margin of white space above the columns.

[image]

Since the three columns are contained within the div class "content", shouldn't all background-colors be turning orange? When I do an inspect element for the section, I notice that it only has a height of 28 pixels, when it should include all three columns' height.

[image]

And when I do an inspect element of the div class "content", the height is at 0px.

[image]

Something's wrong. What am I missing? Thank you!

**EDIT**: In the last two screenshots, I got rid of the h2 "3 Column Layout" thinking it might have been causing the problem, but it wasn't.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SASS Project</title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>

<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div id="container"><!--container-->

<div class="row"><!--first row--> 
<header>  
    <div class="center">                        
       <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
</header>
</div><!--end first row-->

<nav><!--Navigation Bar-->
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<div class="row"><!--second row-->
<div class="col-6">
<article><!--Article-->
<h2>Article</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel
 tortor id 
est imperdiet fermentum. Sed in interdum justo. Cras feugiat
 scelerisque risus 
eu congue. Mauris semper sed neque in pulvinar. Morbi posuere ligula 
in aliquam 
feugiat. Aenean in lectus vel risus vestibulum molestie. Donec mollis
 at odio 
id tempor.</p>
<img src="images/image1.jpg" id="image1">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus 
vel tortor id 
est imperdiet fermentum. Sed in interdum justo. Cras feugiat
 scelerisque risus 
eu congue. Mauris semper sed neque in pulvinar. Morbi posuere ligula
 in aliquam 
feugiat. Aenean in lectus vel risus vestibulum molestie. Donec mollis
 at odio 
id tempor.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel
 tortor id 
est imperdiet fermentum. Sed in interdum justo. Cras feugiat
 scelerisque risus 
eu congue. Mauris semper sed neque in pulvinar. Morbi posuere ligula 
in aliquam 
feugiat. Aenean in lectus vel risus vestibulum molestie. Donec 
mollis at odio
</p>
</article>
</div>


<div class="col-6">
<aside><!--Aside-->
<h2>Aside</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus 
vel tortor id est imperdiet fermentum. Sed in interdum justo. Cras
 feugiat scelerisque risus eu congue. Mauris semper sed neque in
 pulvinar. Morbi posuere ligula in aliquam feugiat. Aenean in lectus
 vel risus vestibulum molestie. Donec mollis at odio id tempor.</p>
<img src="images/image2.jpg" id="image2">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel
 tortor id est imperdiet fermentum. Sed in interdum justo. Cras feugiat
 scelerisque risus eu congue. Mauris semper sed neque in pulvinar.
 Morbi posuere ligula in aliquam feugiat. Aenean in lectus vel risus
 vestibulum molestie. Donec mollis at odio id tempor.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vel
 tortor id est imperdiet fermentum. Sed in interdum justo. Cras feugiat
 scelerisque risus eu congue. Mauris semper sed neque in pulvinar.
 Morbi posuere ligula in aliquam feugiat. Aenean in lectus vel risus
 vestibulum molestie. Donec mollis at odio
</p>
</aside>
</div>
</div><!--end second row-->

<div class="clear">
</div>


<div class="row"><!--third row-->
<section><!--Section-->
    <h2>Section</h2>
<div class="content">

    <div class="col-4">
    <h4>Content 1</h4>
    </div><!--closes leftcol-->

    <div class="col-4">
    <h4>Content 2</h4>
    </div><!--closes midcol-->

    <div class="col-4">
    <h4>Content 3</h4>
    </div><!--closes rightcol-->
</div>
</section>
</div><!--end third row-->


<footer><!--Footer-->
<h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>

</div><!--closes container-->
</body><!--closes body-->

</html>
```

CSS:

```
html{overflow:scroll}/*for tablets and phones*/

*{box-sizing:border-box;}

.row:after{content:"";
       clear:both;
       display:block;}

[class*="col-"]{float:left;
            padding:10px;}


/*global styles*/
#container {height:auto;
        margin:auto;
        max-width:1000px;
        width:100%}

header {width:100%;
   height:40px;
   background-color:red;
   margin-bottom:15px;}

nav ul{list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:15px;}

nav ul li a{display:inline;
        margin-left:15px;
        text-decoration:none;}

nav ul li a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}

h2 {text-align:center;}

.h2Section {background-color:orange;}

h4 {display: block;
text-align:center;}

#image1 {float:left;
    height:160px;
    width:160px;}

#image2 {float:right;
    height:160px;
    width:160px;}

article{width:100%;
    margin-right:5%;
    float:left;
    height:600px;
    background-color:green;
    overflow:scroll;}

aside{width:100%;
  float:right;
  height:600px;
  background-color:green;
  overflow:scroll;}

section {background-color:orange;}

.content{width:auto;
     height:auto;
     background-color:orange;}

.clear{clear:both;}

footer {width:100%;
   height:25px;
   background-color:red;
   margin-bottom:15px;
   clear:both;}

.column {background-color:green;}

/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}

nav ul li {display:inline;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your column divs are floated, they don't automatically expand their parent's height to fit their size. And since there's no other content inside the content div, it's height is 0. You can fix this by adding as the last element inside your content div a div with your `clear` class. This clears the floating, and since that div is positioned below the floated columns and actually counts towards the height of the parent, it will make the content div expand to the height of the columns.

So, the HTML of your content div will now be:

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="col-4">
    <h4>Content 1</h4>
    </div><!--closes leftcol-->

    <div class="col-4">
    <h4>Content 2</h4>
    </div><!--closes midcol-->

    <div class="col-4">
    <h4>Content 3</h4>
    </div><!--closes rightcol-->
    <div class="clear"></div><!-- Clears the floating -->
</div>
```

Here's a working demo on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gjsgob8m/.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can make new CSS class alone
.col-4{background-color:orange;}
the background became orange

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using bootstrap It is the library make life very easy .
http://www.getbootstrap.com

Comment: Just learning web development - what is the difference between bootstrap and what I just did?

Comment: It is a library design to using in responsive design ,provide you a lot of component you need and able you using it very fast instead of make it from beginning ,this series is amazing 
.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJlKos0gePQ&list=PLVDYxb1dYhnqUn0_liNeONyicF1Y3ajLp